# Is material-ui 1.0 planning to support the same api as .18?

Tags: material-ui

I am starting an app with material ui .18. I see that 1.0 is around the corner. I wanted to know what are there plans to support the current api?

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.0, which is maintained on the [next branch](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/next), is going to introduce breaking changes.  The effort appears to include consideration for all of the components that are currently offered, but the API will and overall approach to styles will not be the same.

You can get an idea of the ways it has already deviated by [reviewing the docs](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/) for the next branch.  Also, take a look at the [github project](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/projects/1) for some insight on the roadmap.

The most obvious change is the way styles are handled.  They're using CSS in JS rather than inline styles.  You can read more about that [here](https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/customization/css-in-js).